# Firebase user not save to database when regestering

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

When clicking signup page it doesn't navigate to homepage. And also database is not created  automatically. Although a list is occurring in authentication page. Registration is working.

```
//signuppage.dart

    onPressed: (){
                  var createUserWithEmailAndPassword = FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(

                    email: _email,
                     password: _password);
                  createUserWithEmailAndPassword.then((signedInUser){


                      UserManagement().storeNewUser(signedInUser, context);


                     }).catchError((e){
                       print(e.toString());
                     });

                },
```

here is the usermanagement.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class UserManagement {
    storeNewUser(user, context) {
    Firestore.instance.collection('/users').add({
      'email': user.email,
      'uid': user.uid
    }).then((value) {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');

   }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
   });
   }
   }
```

when app runs this error comming

```
   I/flutter ( 1507): NoSuchMethodError: Class 'AuthResult' has no instance getter 'email'.
   I/flutter ( 1507): Receiver: Instance of 'AuthResult'
   I/flutter ( 1507): Tried calling: email
```

facing this problem cant store data to firebase cloud

Answer (score 2):

The result of authentication is an AuthResult, not a FirebaseUser.

To pass the user to your function, you should send `signedInUser.user` instead of just `signedInUser`

I recommend to you reading the documentation carefully as this things get tricky very fast.

I hope this helps you!

Edit:

I also recommend setting the type of the variables you are using in your functions, that way your IDE would have pointed out the error when typing.

For example you should change

```
storeNewUser(user, context)
```

Into

```
storeNewUser(FirebaseUser user, BuildContext context)
```